# How to change the pager for info command

Tags: linux, gnu, documentation, info

On GNU/Linux is it possible to change the default pager for `info` command? I would like to use `less` as the pager (similar to man pages). I have customized less to use colors to make navigation of man pages much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`info` doesn’t use a separate pager, because it handles navigation — it doesn’t produce a text document to be viewed with another tool. It doesn’t support paging to `less`.

You might find [Pinfo](http://pinfo.sourceforge.net/) interesting, it’s a replacement for `info` (and `man`) with configurable colours etc.